# How To add QR Code In jasper using JasperSoft Studio [Tibco JasperSoft Studio]

Tags: java, qr-code, jaspersoft-studio

For More Detailed Answer Visit :: https://github.com/Amisoni/How-To-add-QR-Code-In-jasper-using-JasperSoft-Studio-Tibco-JasperSoft-Studio

Answer (score 3):

- Configration in JasperSoft Studio

In jasper Studio Select Option Barcode in that Select QR.
In QR Propeties Select Code Expression and add your variable Or Data in Code Expression Field.
Select Now in Evaluation Time.

Add Jar File In JasperSoft Studio For Genrate QR Code.
-> Select Project From Menu -> Propeties -> java build Path -> libraries -> add external jar
select you path where you have download your jar.

- Configration in Your IDE

In your IDE  WebContent/WEB-INF/classes make jasperreports.properties file.

in file Write
net.sf.jasperreports.components.barcode4j.image.producer=image

Add jar Files in you lib folder.

For More Detailed Answer Visit :: https://github.com/Amisoni/How-To-add-QR-Code-In-jasper-using-JasperSoft-Studio-Tibco-JasperSoft-Studio